# How do you handle zeros when logarithmizing?

Tags: fft, audio, audio-processing, librosa

I'm trying to implement a procedure from [a paper](http://www.cp.jku.at/people/schedl/Research/Publications/pdf/MIREX_SSPK2_2010.pdf).
There the authors use two equations to transform a fft transformed music audio file to a cent-spectogram.

Equation 1:

$$ f_{cent} = 1200 \log_{2} \left( \frac{f_{Hz}}{440 \left( \sqrt[1200]{2} \right)^{-5700}} \right) \tag{1} \label{1}$$

Equation 2:

$$ X \left( k \right)_{dB} = 20 \log_{10} \left( X \left( k \right) \right) \tag{2} \label{2} $$

When using `librosa.stft()` I get a lot of low values for many frequencies.
When applying equation \eqref{1} I get negative values or zeros.
Then when using the equation \eqref{2} I get `Nan` or `-Inf`.
For later steps, I use functions like `np.percentile()`, which doesn't work with either of these values.

First i tried setting all values `<= 0` to a small value `(1e^−8)`
so there is no `log(0)` or `log(-n)`. But on the other hand, this procedure distorts the result.

Later I tried setting all `-Inf` to `-1.e+9` to keep a strong contrast between the values but I'm not sure if this is the best way to handle it.

What is your suggestion on how to handle this?

Comment: **1.** I believe that `librosa.stft` returns a complex STFT so if you want to put it through the equation 2 to convert from linear to decibel scale, you need to first take the absolute value of it (`np.abs()`).
**2.** In the equation 2, if you have some values which are zeros, feel free to add some small value in the log (e.g. `20*np.log10(X+1e-12)`)
**3.** Keep in mind that it looks like equation 1 operates only on frequency vector, not the spectrum (it's just a way to warp the frequency scale). In which case it's totally fine to assume that for $f_{Hz}=0=f_{cent}$ - probably need to check.

Comment: What is it that you want?  A spectrogram that displays log amplitude vs. log frequency?  (What we used to call a *"Bode plot"*?)

Comment: Hay @jojeck which post should we respond to?  The other one that you cited as the similar question?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, yes. As I see it this one is a duplicate.

Comment: @jojeck Can you please describe Point 3 with a little more detail? What's the difference between frequency vector and spectrum?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson In the paper they call it a cent-scaled magnitude spectrum. They call it "a fast approximation of a constant-Q transform, but with constant window size for all frequency bins."